# Case Insensitive Search with Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Just an quick and easy one, I need to be able to search our database minus the case sensitivity, I know how to do it, just not with the Neo4jClient. Here's the code:

```
client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person)")
            .Where((Person person) => person.Email == search)
```

where 'search' is a parameter of type string that is passed to the method. I have read that using =~ '(?i)text' works, but that doesn't allow me to pass in the parameter, and I have tried this:

```
client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person)")
            .Where((Person person) => person.Email =~ "(?i){terms}")
            .WithParam("terms",search)
```

But it doesn't like this.

I would like to be able to search without case, and if possible at the same time, using LIKE (or ILIKE as it seems to be for pattern matching).

Thanks

**EDIT & ANSWER**
The final code ended up as this:

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person)")
            .Where("person.Email =~ {terms}")
            .OrWhere("person.Name =~ {terms}")
            .WithParam("terms", "(?ui).*" + search + ".*")
            .Return<Person>("person").Results.ToList();
```

Which does exactly what I want it to.
Also took the advice of a lowercase field with the value in, we already have one in the account so that logon names are not case sensitive, I am going to do this on the email and name fields, seems better than using toLower() (either in Cypher or in C#)

So thank to @Stefan Armbruster for his help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have partial parameters. Instead add `(?i)` to the parameter value:

```
query: person.Email =~ term
parameter: term = "(?i)<myvalue"
```

Note 1: You need to use `(?ui)` for gracefully dealing with non-ascii case sensitivity (e.g. German umlauts).

Note 2: the `=~` operator is not backed by an index, so the query above will touch every `Person` node and apply the regex to the property value. In Neo4j 2.3 there will be a index backed `LIKE` which supports string prefix matches.

If you want to use index based case insensitive search, the recommended approach is to store the property value converted to lower case (Cypher has a `toLower` function) and then do a exact match on the lower cased search value.

Comment: Is like search(property=~'.*(?i)VALUE.*') using index from Neo4j 2.3 ?

Comment: `=~` does not use the index in 2.3. Only `STARTS WITH` does.